# Don't change replace with string Java

Tags: java, string, replace, char

I wite program which pulls the last six characters
this my code

```
String numberString;
int number=123456;

// convert int to string
numberString = String.valueOf(number);
char[] chars = new char[7];
String napis = "S4P6W7M522SC3OXX55K3NN77666N34M2";
char[] array = napis.toCharArray();

// loop which pulls the last six characters
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i >= 26 && i <= 32) {
        chars[index] = array[i];
        index++;
    }

}

String Str = new String(napis);
System.out.print("String: " + napis);
// convert char to string
String kod = String.valueOf(chars);
System.out.print("Result " + kod);
// show new String
String newString = napis.replace(kod, numberString);
System.out.print("New String: " + newString);
```

// Show output

```
Please write  six number
    123456
    String: S4P6W7M522SC3OXX55K3NN77666N34M2
    Result 6N34M2
    New String: S4P6W7M522SC3OXX55K3NN77666N34M2
```

should be

```
    New String: S4P6W7M522SC3OXX55K3NN7766123456
```

I don't have idea why replace is it is incorrect

Comment: Why not simply using substring to remove the last 6 character ? Please define `Character` too ;)

Comment: Why do you assume `numberString` is 123456? Could you make an output of `numberString` and `number` before replacing?

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you are using an array of 7 character, if you check the length of the String you are build (`kod`) with this array, you will get 7 characters, so it can't match the substring you are trying to replace that only do 6 character. (you have character of 0 at the end (the value, not the number)

Use an array of 6

```
 char[] chars = new char[6];
```

To prevent this problem.

---

This is a bit risky if your String is **shorter than 32 character**. You could simply read the array from the end, and only read 6 character (or until you reach the index 0)

---

But you can also have **the last 6character sequence somewhere else in the String**. That will replace the first sequence too (if you use `replaceAll()`) or only the first one with the current code

---

Using a substring to remove the last 6 character would be simpler and safer.

Just need to be sure you will have a String of at least 6 character, the trick is to use Math.max :

```
napis.substring(0, Math.max(napis.length() - 6, 0)) + numberString;
```

`Math.max` will only give 0 if the String is to short.

Comment: @Paulina, Remember that an array of primitive (char/int/double) set the cell to `0` by default, so your String was like `"6N34M2"0`.

Comment: @Paulina, don't forget to accept the answer if it suits you. See the [tour] to see how StackOverflow is working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple approach for the solution.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class replace {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=s.nextInt();
        String aa=Integer.toString(a);
        String b=s.next();
        String bb=b.substring(b.length()-6);
        System.out.println(aa+" "+bb);
        String bc=b.replace(bb,aa);
        System.out.println(bc);
     }

}
```